# Limit on DDS topic names

Tags: publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service

I am currently using **RTI DDS** and am writing some specifications. However, I don't want any of the topic names in my specifications to over exceed the limit for the topic name in `DDS`. I tried searching and could not find if any such limit exist. Does anyone happen to know if `DDS` limits your topic name to a certain length of if it is just to not exceed the limit on the length of a `String` for whatever language you are programming in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OMG standard for DDS (rev 1.2) does not supply an arbitrary limit to Topic name length.

> A **Topic** is identified by its **name**, *which must be unique in the whole Domain*.

According to the RTI documentation (5.1.0 Users Guide pdf, Section 5.1.1, page 170), RTI's implementation of the Standard implements an arbitrary limit:

> topic_name     |     Name for the new Topic, must not exceed 255 characters

This appears to be the length max for ***any*** Entity (you can name entities in its QoS, so that tools can report human-readable names for which Entity they are reporting on).

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that the DDS API specification does not mention a limit for Topic names. The complementary DDS Wire Protocol specification: Real-Time Publish Subscribe (RTPS) protocol (http://www.omg.org/spec/DDSI-RTPS/2.2), does state that Topic names shall not exceed 256 characters (see Table 9.12).

So the 256 character limit on Topic name lengths imposed by the RTI DDS implementation **is not arbitrary**. It is precisely what is required to be interoperable with other DDS implementations.

Gerardo